# Dired+. Autorefresh after copy files

Tags: dired, revert-buffer

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Dired+.

I copy file from one folder to another.
Here screens:

[image: Screen_1]

After copy I get the next result:

[image: Second]

As you can see the bottom buffer is not refresh. 
So I need to go to bottom buffer and press `g` for refresh.

[image: Third]

The question is: Is it possible Emacs/Dired+ to autorefresh buffer after copy file?

Answer (score 1):

Hm.  I don't see that behavior.  What I see is that the file that was copied shows up immediately in the Dired listing of the directory where it was copied.

Did you try with `emacs -Q` and then just loading `dired+.el`?

---

If you do need to force reverting for some reason, and you don't want to use `g`, you can also try periodic auto-reverting.

The Emacs manual, node [Reverting](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Reverting.html) tells you:

> You can also tell Emacs to revert buffers periodically.  To do this
>   for a specific buffer, enable the minor mode Auto-Revert mode by typing
>   **`M-x auto-revert-mode`**.  This automatically reverts the current buffer
>   every five seconds; you can change the interval through the variable
>   `auto-revert-interval`.

---

But again, you should not have the behavior you are seeing.  The copied file should show up in the target directory listing.

Comment: With minimal configuration. Only dired+ it' success autorefresh.

Comment: Dunno what to say. It works for me, in all Emacs releases. And I too am on MS Windows. I start Emacs with `emacs -Q`, load `dired+.el`, visit a directory and one of its subdirectories (two windows), and copy (`C`) a file from the parent directory to the subdirectory. The copied file shows up in the subdir Dired buffer, with mark `C` in the left column and with the entire line highlighted, to show that it was created by copying.

Comment: FWIW, your screenshots indicate that you also are using Helm, yas, and Async.

Comment: Ah, I see you changed your comment to indicate that it **does** work OK with just Dired+. So you need to bisect your init file to find out which other code is interfering with the proper behavior. (Perhaps "Async?")

Comment: I found the problem. In my init.el I has `(dired-async-mode t)`. If comment this than problem is gone.  But I need to set this variable because I want to asyn copy.

Comment: I assume you see the same thing with vanilla Dired, i.e., starting from `emacs -Q` and not loading Dired+. If not, then let me know. But if so, consider filing a bug or enhancement request with the maintainer of dired-async (John Wiegley), saying something like you want the buffer reverted even when you have `dired-async-mode` turned on. But I suspect there is a good reason that this reverting doesn't happen automatically for async.